# James went to the campus cafe. Is went transitive or intransitive verb? campus cafe is direct object so it should be but it isn't. Why?

Tags: verbs, transitivity

What I observe is campus cafe is a direct object, it receives the action, went is an action verb so it should be transitive. But here: http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/intransitiveverb.htm it says it is intransitive. Can someone explain what is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that "Campus cafe" is *not* the direct object of the verb "went." "Campus cafe" is the object of the preposition "to". You might want to read [Chompchomp](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/directobject.htm)'s article about direct objects.

They (Chompchomp) are right that "went" is intransitive. That means we don't say, "James went the cafe."
If you want to say **where** James went, you can use "to" (a preposition): "James went **to** the cafe."

Comment: You may be right, but it's kind of splitting hairs.  You can't say *"James went"* by itself, so it's problematic to call it an *intransitive* verb.  There's probably some other term that applies, although I don't know what it would be.

Comment: Then why can we say *James went home*, *James went crazy*, or *James went bar hopping*? We don't use *to* with those expressions. It seems to me that the presence of lack of *to* has more to do with what follows it than the verb itself. So, I don't think the *to* is a good indicator of it being transitive or intransitive.

Comment: @Andrew a transitive verb is a verb that requires a direct object. Objects are virtually always NPs. "To school" in "James went to school" can be considered a locative complement

Comment: @Jason "Home" is a preposition and therefore does not function as object. "Crazy" is a predicative complement. "Bar-hoping" is either an adjunct or a complement but it's more likely to be a complement. An object is virtually always realized by an NP. "Went" is clearly intransitive here.

Comment: @user178049 Referring to Merriam-Webster, [*home*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/home) can be a noun, adverb, adjective, or verb. It has no entry for it being a preposition. In *I went home*, it's being used as an adverb. I also never said that *home* functioned as an object. If I'm interpreting what you're saying correctly, the answer we're commenting on should be edited to say that *went* cannot be followed by a ***noun***. The way it's currently written, the explanation is unclear.

Comment: @Jason Merriam-Webster is actually very bad when it comes to parts of speech. See [Araucaria's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/385474/178049) and [this entry](https://simple.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/home)

Comment: @user178049 Regardless of terminology and appeals to authority, the point is that this answer needs to be clarified.

Comment: @Andrew, I'm not sure I agree that *"you can't say **James went** by itself."   *Did he stay or did he go? -- James went.*  It is fine for "to go" to be an intransitive verb.

Comment: @whiskeychief  I'm not really arguing.  Rather I'm saying that the verb "to go" always begs for more information.  Unlike most intransitive verbs, such as *"the car **stopped**"*, you can't say *"it went"* without including context, which makes me feel as if it's some other species of grammar animal.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, of course you can say "James went." as a complete sentence by itself. It is also true that lots of complete sentences beg, even *cry out*, for more information. You can still say them. [Example: "He has not been seen since."] Why does "it went" require more information, but "the car **stopped**" is valid as-is. Don't you need to know why it stopped? ... Brakes, or out of gas?

Comment: Can an object belong to a preposition and a verb at the same time? Here went has to have an object. Ins't it true?

Comment: @J.Smith No, when you are analyzing the grammar (in English) of how a sentence is put together, an object can't belong to a preposition and a verb at the same time. Also, "went" does not always have to have an object: "There was a party, and all of my roommates went."; "Even back in those days, some of the cars went pretty fast."; "We just watched as the girls went by." "Pretty fast" and "by" aren't objects.

Comment: @Andrew I am baffled that you can say it is "problematic" to call "**went**" [= past of "**to go**"] an intransitive verb. Am I misunderstanding you here? Merriam-Webster, Longman, and MacMillan all have "**go**" as intransitive, with a few minor exceptions like: "...no one for to go my bail", and "The cow goes 'mooooo'."

Comment: @LorelC.  Eh, it was just an offhand observation, in the hope that one of the more scholarly contributors here would chime in.  Superficially I think it's fine to call it an intransitive verb, but I suspect down where the nitty meets the gritty some linguists may still be uncomfortable.